# dataWithJSONObject with NSDate

Tags: ios, json

Does anyone know how I might use dataWithJSONObject to serialized a dictionary or array that contains an NADate object?  SBJSON has a user definable method that can be provided for this. Is there something similar with NSJSONSerialization ?

Answer (score 0):

dataWithJSONObject serialise NSDate into String however doesn't deserialise it back. So the solution can be use String or NSDate.timeIntervalSince1970 instead inside NSDictionary values and then NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970)